# how to pass arguments directly to awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a file which has columns seperated by delimiter( space in this case).

to print columns i use,

```
awk ' { print $1 "," $3 } filename
```

this prints columns 1 and 3 seperated by commas.

now i want to send `$1 "," $3` as an argument. so that i can change it to something like `$1 "-" $3` and i should also be able to change the number of arguments later like `$1 "," $2 "-" $3`.

Aim is to pass the fields and delimiters dynamically ie., awk command will be in one file and the pattern should be passed as an argument. Is it possible

eg.

trigger.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

var="\$1\"\,\"\$2" #this is $1","$2

sh test.sh $var
```

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -v var="$1" ' { print var}' data.dat
```

data.dat contains the actual data

but i am unable to get the desired output.

output :

```
awk: warning: escape sequence `\,' treated as plain `,'
$1","$2 --> printing this instead of columns
```

Comment: dont escape $, otherwise you will get $1,$2

Comment: `awk` doesn't support evaluating a formatted command like that.

Comment: @MaheshKharvi tried the same way. but it too dint work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to pass the arguments/variable value dynamically. I found a way to do that.

```
Str="awk ' { print "

t="\$1\",\"\$2 } ' " 
# above expression will be passed as an argument and will be assigned to variable t 

Str="$Str""$t""data.dat"

echo "$Str"
```

now this string Str has value as shown below

```
awk ' { print $1","$2" } ' data.dat
```

now all we need to do is

```
eval $Str
```

this solution worked absolutely fine for me.